# Add a column if not exists in table

Tags: mysql

I want to add a column which will be added in table only if column with same name is not exists.
Alter Table tablename
add col varchar(250)

Comment: There is no IF NOT EXIST for adding columns, you will have to check this in a separate Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cant just execute your SQL and retrieve the error if the column already exists.

On the other hand, if you don't want to reach a possible error situation at the MySQL side you could try something like (dynamic SQL):

```
SET @query = (SELECT
    IF((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=database() AND      
     TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'COL')=0,
     CONCAT('ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE ADD COLUMN COL varchar(255)'),
 'SELECT ''ALREADY EXISTS'''
 ));
PREPARE st FROM @query;
EXECUTE st;
```

First, you will generate a SQL containing the column addition SQL or a dummy SQL depending on whether you already have the target column at the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

```
PREPARE
```

and

```
EXECUTE
```

statements are used to execute that query.

Answer (score 0):

use INFORMATION_SCHEMA database

```
SELECT 
count(*) 
FROM
information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE
information_schema.TABLE_SCHEMA=DB name
AND information_schema.TABLE_NAME=table name
AND information_schema.COLUMN_NAME=col name
```

if count is more than 0 create the column else don't

Comment: Can you please add code for checking count in IF

Comment: @user1280492 You can't check it in a single SQL outside a stored procedure or a dynamic sql.